# multi tenant application on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, multi-tenant

Note: I edited this question because I try to ask more as a question not as an opinion.

Our application is a multi tenant application being developed using Java, JBoss, and MySQL on Linux.

if application is multi-tenancy should we launch 1 instance per customer or or should we launch 1 instance for all customers ?

When and why we should launch new instance while we have one already?

Thanks
Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

This is not a great question for here since the questions are likely to be a bit too opinionated. But I will give you some thoughts about what you wrote.

1. Having one customer confined to one instance gives you no failover. If the instance fails, the application is down until you can restart or relaunch the instance.
2. You should probably think about building clusters than can host several customers, 2-4 instances each, with failover and load balancing. (Maybe also use Multi-AZ RDS to host mysql)
3. Customer specific configuration needs to get out of JBoss and into your application somehow, I dont know the details of the platform so I cannot provide specifics.

Answer (score 1):

Whether to launch one instance per customer or not is purely based on the solution you want to provide, the requirement, the load and the multi tenant strategy you decide to use. There is no fixed answer.

If all the tenants load can be sustained by one instance and you are not worried about per tenant resource usage then one instance is just enough. Of Course, you will plan for high availability.
Here are a few answers i provided for other users questions regarding db design and scalability for a saas setup. I hope it helps.

[Databse architecture (single db vs client specific db) for Building Enterprise Web (RIA) application on cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683213/databse-architecture-single-db-vs-client-specific-db-for-building-enterprise-w/15697362#15697362)

[Explanation of Tenant Load Balancer in SaaS maturity model level 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382787/explanation-of-tenant-load-balancer-in-saas-maturity-model-level-4/16826807#16826807)

[Architecture for SaaS based online portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859245/architecture-for-saas-based-online-portal/16827027#16827027)