# Database Schema for Multi tenant SaaS Application

Tags: database, database-design, multi-tenant, saas

I want to know how to provide customization to each tenant. I want to provide the facility to add new fields in each form a tenant wants with field name, data type etc. Now my question is how to design database tables for this type of scenario ? As I have thought we will have to give form id to each form and whenever a Tenant creates a new field in the form, a new row in the database table should be created which should have Tenant id, Form id, Field name, Data type etc....

Now please give me true solution friends.... I need the database table design solution for this immediately...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683213/databse-architecture-single-db-vs-client-specific-db-for-building-enterprise-w/15697362#15697362

Answer (score 3):

Using SQL, tenants can share a database cluster, a database, or a table. Terminology varies.

When tenants share a database cluster, each tenant has a private database. This is the easiest to customize, has the strongest isolation among tenants, and is the easiest to recover in a disaster.

When tenants share a database, each tenant gets a private schema. This is also pretty easy to customize, has somewhat less isolation among tenants, and is still relatively easy to recover in a disaster. Recovery for one tenant will probably affect the performance of all tenants, though.

When tenants share a table, each tenant gets some private rows, so to speak. This is very hard to customize at even a small scale, isolation among tenants is harder, and disaster recovery for a single tenant is *really* hard.

I think your best bet is one database per tenant or one schema per tenant. But you should be aware that expecting end users to be database designers is risky.